# Таймер в Android-приложении

Tags: android, java

Как сделать таймер в android-приложении? Просто использовать [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Есть в ОС вот что — [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)
А вообще вот Вам примерчик:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new UpdateTimeTask(), 0, 1000); //тикаем каждую секунду без задержки 
//задача для таймера
class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        ...
    } 
}
```

На самом деле, попробуйте сперва `CountDownTimer`.
А, вспомнил. Вот вам еще [дока](https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html).

Только таймер работает один раз (тот что `java.util.Timer`), такая у него особенность, и нужно перехватывать `IllegalStateException`.

Answer (score 7):

Можно с помощью CountDownTimer.

```
public class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer
{

    public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
          super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
        // Do something...
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен простой таймер, можно использовать [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html).

Например, в `layout` помещаем `chronometer`:

```
<Chronometer
android:id="@+id/chronometer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

В `Activity` инициализируем `Chronometer`, получаем время с момента старта приложения и устанавливаем его в качестве базового для нашего `Cronometer`:

```
Chronometer chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
chronometer.setBase(startTime);
```

Получаем на экране обычный тикающий таймер.

Формат вывода времени можно поменять в `setFormat(String format)`