# Действие по таймеру

Tags: android

Как выполнить определенное действие по истечению заданного таймера?
Вообще, нужно показывать диалог по истечению 3-х секунд

Comment: Зависит от реализации Вашего таймера.

Comment: @post_zeew, написал выше

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Таймер в Android-приложении](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/25779/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-android-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно запустить поток и сделать необходимую задержку:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // действия после задержки
    }
}).start();
```